# Pull adjacent table cell using BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

```
table = plan1.find('table', id = 'planComparison')
pcp = table.findChildren(text=' Doctor Visit - Primary Care ')
```

I've used the above code to set the pcp variable to the cell which says ' Doctor Visit - Primary Care '.  I need info from the cell next to it (it will vary from case to case).

How can I pull the adjacent cell?  Is there a way to return the row number of the pcp variable's cell?  Any input is appreciated.

[Source url](https://dc.checkbookhealth.org/hie/dc/2016/plan.cfm?data=eyJGT1JNVkFMVUVTIjp7fSwiVVJMVkFMVUVTIjp7IkNPVkVSQUdFIjoiSW5kaXZpZHVhbCIsImVmZmVjdGl2ZURhdGUiOiIiLCJob3VzZWhvbGROdW1iZXIiOjEsImFnZSI6MjEsInBsYW5MaXN0IjoiODYwNTJEQzA0MDAwMDQtMDEiLCJkb2N0b3JBdXRvQ29tcGxldGUiOiIiLCJmaW5kU3Vic2lkeSI6ZmFsc2UsImluY29tZSI6IiIsImNhbGN1bGF0ZVN1YnNpZHkiOiIiLCJuYXRpdmUiOjAsImhlYWx0aFN0YXR1cyI6IiIsImNvdW50eSI6Ildhc2hpbmd0b24gREMiLCJlbXBsb3llckNvdmVyYWdlIjpmYWxzZSwicHJlZ25hbnQiOjAsIm1lZGljYWxFeHBlbnNlIjoiIiwiZGF0YSI6IiJ9fQ%3D%3D)

Comment: note that plan1 = soup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the next `td`, use the `nextSibling` function.  It can be a little tricky because blank spaces can be considered the next sibling, so you have to try a few things.  I modified your code to be:

```
table = plan1.find('table', id = 'planComparison')
pcp = table.find('td',text=' Doctor Visit - Primary Care ')
print(pcp.nextSibling.nextSibling.text)
```

The output is:

```
Copay: No Charge after deductible; Coinsurance: No Charge after deductible
```

Note I had to call `nextSibling` twice to get to the `td` tag you wanted, and then called `text` to get rid of the `<td>` tags.

Also note that I specified that you wanted a `td` in the `find` instead of the general `findChildren`.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for your help.